# FreeBSD bandwidth throttling per IP

Tags: freebsd

I have a public HTTP server running FreeBSD.

Nginx allows me to limit throughput per connection, but I don't want to limit each IP to only 1 connection so I need a solution to limit per IP. Nginx cannot do that for me and the 3rd party modules to do it are no longer maintained.

With nginx not being an option I figure something OS level should be able to handle it, but all the other questions and answers all seem to assume I know the IPs I want to traffic shape from. Since my server is a public HTTP server I don't want to traffic shape for a specific set of IPs but rather for every IP, and grouped by the IP.

Is there any way FreeBSD can possible limit throughput per IP for all IPs?

On a side note, my backup solution is Varnish which does seem to support this scenario but would be an extra piece of software to support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there is. It's called *dynamic queues* if you need prioretization, or *dynamic pipes* is you need shaping, both implemented in *DUMMYNET*. It's possible to combine these two to make a real CBQ-coniguration.

A brief example on dynamic pipes from [man 8 ipfw](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ipfw&sektion=8&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2011.0-RELEASE):

> A more sophisticated example is limiting the outbound traffic on a net
>       with per-host limits, rather than per-network limits:
>
> ```
> ipfw add pipe 1 ip from 192.168.2.0/24 to any out
> ipfw add pipe 2 ip from any to 192.168.2.0/24 in
> ipfw pipe 1 config mask src-ip 0x000000ff bw 200Kbit/s queue 20Kbytes
> ipfw pipe 2 config mask dst-ip 0x000000ff bw 200Kbit/s queue 20Kbytes
> ```

I think you could also enable HTTP/2 in nginx, thus diminishing the number of connections that is used by each HTTP/2-capable client.

Comment: How would this handle under load? Server is frequently pushing 1gbps.

Comment: It's pps that really matters, not the bandwidth. Anyway, I think it will perform just fine, being properly configured. Gyes at russian search engine called Yandex experiment with loads up to 40 Gbits/sec.

Comment: Thanks, will try to set this up and let you know how it works.